# 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'const wchar_t *'

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm trying to compile some old game SRC I found on the net here's the code

```
bool LoadFromINI(std::wstring const& strINIFileName = _T("./Local.ini"), char const* szDefaultLocale = "");
bool LoadFromINB(std::wstring const& strINBFileName, wchar_t const* szDefaultLocale = _T(""));


C:\...\...Code\Cel_Convert_Source\Cosmos\include\BM/LocalMgr.h(60): error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'const wchar_t *'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>C:\...\...Code\Cel_Convert_Source\Cosmos\include\BM/LocalMgr.h(60): error C2548: 'LOCAL_MGR::CLocal::LoadFromINB' : missing default parameter for parameter 2
1>C:\...\...Code\Cel_Convert_Source\Cosmos\include\BM/LocalMgr.h(59): error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'const char [12]' to 'const std::wstring &'
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'const char [12]' to 'const std::wstring'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>C:\...\...Code\Cel_Convert_Source\Cosmos\include\BM/LocalMgr.h(103): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

One more error: 
Code:

> ```
>       _tcscpy_s(m_kDBName,30, (wchar_t const*)in_strDBName);
> ```

Output:

> 'errno_t strcpy_s(char *,rsize_t,const char *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'const char *'
>   1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: Sorry, nope! We don't have an answer for this ...

Comment: Initializing a `std::wstring` with the result of `_T` makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

Change `_T("blah")` to `L"blah"`.

`_T` is a macro that does nothing or adds an `L`.

Alternatively, compile project with the wchar option for `_T` and `TCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

The `_T("str")` expands to `L"str"` only if your project is compiled with the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol defined. In your case, it seems it isn't, so `_T()` does nothing. Change the function declarations to

```
bool LoadFromINI(std::wstring const& strINIFileName = L"./Local.ini", wchar_t const* szDefaultLocale = "");
bool LoadFromINB(std::wstring const& strINBFileName, wchar_t const* szDefaultLocale = L"");
```

or if you really, really must support the `_T()` and `TCHAR` stuff, change them to

```
bool LoadFromINI(std::basic_string<TCHAR> const& strINIFileName = _T("./Local.ini"), TCHAR const* szDefaultLocale = "");
bool LoadFromINB(std::basic_string<TCHAR> const& strINBFileName, TCHAR const* szDefaultLocale = _T(""));
```

Now the first argument will be either `std::string` or `std::wstring` depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined.

Comment: @user3302898 It depends on what your goal is. My advice is to stick to `wstring` and `wchar_t` when dealing with WinAPI. It's very unlikely you need to support `TCHAR` switching.

Comment: One more thing what about this error.
Code:
   _tcscpy_s(m_kDBName,30, (wchar_t const*)in_strDBName);
Output:
 error C2664: 'errno_t strcpy_s(char *,rsize_t,const char *)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'const char *'

Comment: @user3302898 It's the same deal, `_tcscpy_s` will expand to `strcpy_s` or the wide char equivalent (`wcscpy_s`), depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined. Stop using the `TCHAR` macros and explicitly use the wide char functions/types.

Comment: Okay so I did    
wcscpy_s(m_kDBName,30, (wchar_t const*)in_strDBName); is that correct?

Comment: @user3302898 It's hard to say without knowing the types of the variables involved. Why do you need to cast the third argument to `wchar_t const *`?